# The same text that is wrapped inside a div, will overflow the same div after it is inserted by Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a div that is initialized with some text:

```
<div id="previewText" style="margin: 10px auto; width:366px; background: #EDEDED; border: solid 1px #CCC; padding: 10px; word-wrap: normal; font-size: 13px; font-family: 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;">
   word1 word2 word3333 word444444 word55555 word666666 word777777 word888888 word999999 word1000000 word11111111 word222222222 word333333333   
</div>
```

and I see this on the browser:

[image: text1]

Then, If i append the same text from a `textarea` to the exact div:

***The text area:***

[image: textarea]

***The Javascript code***

```
var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("fbMessage");
var textAreaText = TheTextBox.value;

previewText = textAreaText.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>").replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp");

document.getElementById('previewText').innerHTML = previewText;
```

The new appended text is exceeding the width of the div, and I see this:

[image: text2]

I've tried changing the div to a table and put the text inside a `<td>`. But the same thing happens.

Why is this happening? And how can I preserve the text inside the div after the copy?

**Note: I dont want to use `word-wrap: break-word;` because dont want to break any words

Comment: You're replacing with `&nbsp` (should actually be `&nbsp;`) which is a "**non-breaking** space".

Comment: @thirtydot What do I need to change it to ? I also want to preserve spaces and new lines. But I want the text to fit in the width of the div.

Comment: Of course it exceeds the width, you're still using a "---> **non-breaking** <--- space". Try with `.replace(/\s/g, " ");` instead, but I don't see the point of the replacement in the first place.

Comment: @thirtydot Actually, you are right, there is no point for the replacement. I've removed it totally and just using `textAreaText.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");` which works great. Thanks, post an answer if you want ;0)

Comment: @thirtydot Another small question if i may, How can I (by the Javascript) replace multiple repeated new lines into a single new line ? thanks.

Comment: `textAreaText.replace(/\n+/g, "<br/>");`.

Comment: @thirtydot Thanks a lot for the help, One really last thing if possible. I want multiple repeated new lines will be converted to one new blank line, can this be done ?

Comment: `textAreaText.replace(/\n+/g, "<br/><br />")` or even better wrap the whole thing in `<p>...</p>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "overflow: hidden;" to the div's style declaration.

If that doesn't work, try removing the "word-wrap" rule, you may not need that.